# Encoding large images into base64 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, string, file, post, base64

I'm using a simple form that posts an image to my server in the form of a base64 string. When I upload small images (< 500 kb) it works perfectly for .jpg and .png files. But when the size is for example 4 mb the function does nothing, doesn't even print the *alert*:

HTML:

```
<form action="/nuevo_cuadro" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input id="foto" type="file" name="foto" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="encodeImageFileAsURL();">Upload</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("foto").files;
    var filename = document.getElementById("foto").value;

    var regex = /.*\\(.*)/;
    var match = regex.exec(filename);

    filename = match[1];

    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

            alert(srcData);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/upload/' + filename,
                data: srcData,
                dataType: "text",
                contentType:"text/plain"
            });
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you deliberately trying to do two HTTP POST operations? You've got `<input type="submit">` so as soon as the JS function returns the HTTP form POST is performed and you're off. If you change to `<input type="button">` then the post doesn't get performed by the form and you should be able to start debugging.

Also, I'm not sure what's going to happen when you try to alert out a base64 encoded image that's a few megabytes big!

I had success by paring down your example to this:

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("foto").files;

    var file = filesSelected[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function (f) {
        return function (e) {
            alert('***got here***');
        };
    })(file);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

With the button changed to type button, not submit.

Comment: Yes I'm posting to two different methods in my backend because I'm using a very "beta" framework and also I have no knowledge to make it better.